# How to use SELECT query multiple times on same column, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to generate two columns based on crosstab information.  Specifically, I am trying to select students who asked questions in a discussion forum, and put them into a "questioners" column and select students who answered questions, and put them in an "answerers" column.  The queries work individually, but when I join them by a comma as follows, I get this syntax error:

```
SELECT author_id AS questioner
WHERE post_type='question',
group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") AS answerers
WHERE post_type='answer'
FROM students;
```

SYNTAX ERROR:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") AS answerers
FROM students
WHERE' at line 12
```

How do I get a column of people asking questions and a column of those answering questions? I assume that the error comes from misunderstanding SELECT syntax.

Comment: What is the relation in the row between the question and the answer?

Comment: Each row is a post made by a student. It is classified as either a "question," "answer," or "comment."

Comment: And could you give an example of what output you expect from your query? It's not very clear

Comment: I expect an answer column filled with students who answered a given question and a question column filled with students who asked a question that began a thread.

Comment: Just give an example of a row

Comment: ROW: [Jenny......James John Jill] where Jenny asked a question that started off the thread and James, John, and Jill all answered the question.

Comment: Alright, thats what i thought, and none of the answers below will do it. Just a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i think it's what you want:

```
SELECT
  s1.author_id AS questioner,
  (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") FROM students s2 WHERE s2.post_type = 'answer' AND s2.thread_id = s1.thread_id) AS answerers
FROM
  students s1
WHERE
  s1.post_type = 'question'
```

Comment: Holy moly, it worked. Can you explain what s1 and s2 are please? Don't feel obligated to if you'd rather go get on with other questions.

Comment: They are just aliases of the table so that we can join them on each other. It's the same principal as when your aliasing a column with AS. (: So what is happening is that we are doing a subquery for every question and joining it on the thread_id. Hope that answers your question. (:

Comment: @goldisfine this was btw. exactly what was explained in the link I posted for you :-D Just from your question it was hard for me to understand what you wanted to achieve exactly, and in the end it's better if you build the queries yourself, in case you want to change them later ...

Answer (score 3):

I know this works in SQL server, but you can try in MySQL

```
SELECT a.author_id AS questioner, b.author_id AS answerers
FROM students a, students b
WHERE a.post_type='question'
AND b.post_type='answer'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this rely on me having two different tables: a and b?

Comment: No, a and b are just different aliases from the same table `students`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you want to issue two FROM in the first place (which aren't allowed anyways). If you want to get two selections in a single query, you could do this (query not tested):

```
SELECT author_id, post_type AS questioner
FROM students
WHERE post_type='question' OR post_type='answer';
```

If you need to do two queries in a single statement, you need to use subqueries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html